# Collect results of forEach in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to collect the values returned by a method called inside a `forEach`:

```
@PostMapping(value="insert-ppl")
public String insertPeople(@RequestBody @Valid @NotNull List<Person> people){
    people.forEach(this::insertPerson);
}
```

the `insertPerson` method returns a string signaling whether the insert in the database was successfull or not. I want to take the strings returned from each call to the `insertPerson`. But I can't use the `.collect` because is not a stream.

How can I do that?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `map` instead of `forEach` if you care about the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `forEach` is supposed to be used to execute a consuming operation on each element. It's not supposed to be used to collect any results.

For this purpose you need to do it differently. I think best option would be to just use a standard `for` loop and add result of each `insertPerson` call into a list that you then return at the end.

Theoretically, you could use something like `people.stream().map(this::insertPerson).toList()` but that's in my opinion not great idea, because `map()` is supposed to just map input to output without any side effects, however your `insertPerson` obviously has side effects, which may make it more "problematic" for a reader to understand what is really happening.

Comment: After the first comment I was going for ```people.stream().map(this::insertPerson).collect(Collectors.toList());``` but with your answer I understand that map wouldn't be used properly here. I'm going with a classic ```for``` loop.

Comment: What's the difference between ```collect(Collectors.toList())``` and ```toList()``` ?

Comment: `toList` returns a list that is guaranteed to be unmodifiable.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of reasons why this code isn't suitable for streams.

Firstly, your goal is to operate via *side-effects* (because you need to update the database), the only operations which are intended for such cases are `forEach()` and `forEachOrdered()`. And as [*API documentation worns*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#SideEffects) these methods should be used with great care.

Note that `map()` isn't suitable for that purpose, it wasn't designed to operate via side-effects. And intermediate operations like `map()` in some cases could be optimized away from the stream. It's not likely to happen in a pipeline build like that: `stream().map().collect()`, but the key point is that intermediate operations semantically are **not intended** to perform *resulting actions*, in your case call `insertPerson()` is a resulting action and accumulated string is only a byproduct.

For your purposes, you can still use `Iterable.forEach()`.

```
@PostMapping(value = "insert-ppl")
public String insertPeople(@RequestBody @Valid @NotNull List<Person> people) {

    StringJoiner result = new StringJoiner("\n"); // provide the required delimiter instead of "\n"

    people.forEach(person -> result.add(insertPerson(person)));

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Great answer and great link! I know I shouldn't use comments in this way but thank you!!